# Difference between keras.backend.max and keras.backend.argmax

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0

I am a beginner in Deep Learning and while performing a practical assignment, came across the Keras documentation on keras.backend.

I went through the explanation a number of times. however, i cannot exactly understand the difference between max and argmax function.

Answer (score 0):

`argmax` is the index of maximum in an array and `max` is maximum value in that array. Please check the example given below

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.constant([1,10,2,4,15])
print(tf.keras.backend.argmax(x, axis=-1).numpy()) # output 4 (index of max value 15, which is 4)
print(tf.keras.backend.max(x, axis=-1).numpy()) # output 15
```

Comment: Thank you. I got clarification